# QGIS 3.4 Processing Python Scripts folder default configuration is lost

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3, qgis-3

I have lost the default configuration of the 'Processing Python Scripts folder' on QGIS 3.4 and in consecuence some Python processing scripts and plugins cannot work properly because they cannot find the path to their resources.

Does any one knows wich are the default configuration paths of the processing scripts folder?

[image]

This is the error msg:

2018-12-19T10:51:17     WARNING    warning:C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\objcreator.py:152: DeprecationWarning: 'U' mode is deprecated
              plugin = open(filename, 'rU')

```
         traceback: File "", line 1, in 
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 335, in startPlugin
          plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
          File "D:/Users/gasato/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DigitizingTools\__init__.py", line 28, in classFactory
          from .digitizingtools import DigitizingTools
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 672, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 728, in exec_module
          File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "D:/Users/gasato/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DigitizingTools\digitizingtools.py", line 33, in 
          from .dtDialog import DigitizingToolsAbout
          File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 672, in _import
          mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
          File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
          File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
          File "", line 728, in exec_module
          File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "D:/Users/gasato/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\DigitizingTools\dtDialog.py", line 27, in 
          os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ui_about.ui'))
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 198, in loadUiType
          winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, code_string, from_imports, resource_suffix, import_from)
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\Compiler\compiler.py", line 53, in __init__
          qtproxies.QtWidgets, CompilerCreatorPolicy())
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\uiparser.py", line 177, in __init__
          self.factory = QObjectCreator(creatorPolicy)
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\objcreator.py", line 85, in __init__
          if self.load_plugin(filename, plugin_globals, plugin_locals):
          File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\objcreator.py", line 152, in load_plugin
          plugin = open(filename, 'rU')
```